# How should I type React's dispatch function to be able to do a "then" method like a Promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-promise-middleware

I have a simple app which dispatches an action on first load to populate the store. I want to be able to run a `then` method on `dispatch` but typescript complains about this.

(According to redux's documentation, the return value of dispatching an action is the [return value of the action itself](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction))

Code available in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-paper-cx1l38)

```
// app.jsx
function App() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodos()).then((todos) => console.log(todos));
    //                   ^^^^^
    //                   Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ type: "GET_TODOS"; payload: Promise<AxiosResponse<Todo[], any>>; }'.
  }, []);
  return <div className="App">Hello World!</div>;
}
```

### Store Configuration

I use `@reduxjs/toolkit` to configure my store and have a `redux-promise-middleware` set up for it so that upon "fulfillment" of my promised-based actions an `<ACTION>_FULFILLED` action will also be dispatched.

```
// store.ts
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import rootReducer from './reducer';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [promiseMiddleware],
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export default store;
```

### Reducer

```
// reducer.ts
import produce, { Draft } from "immer";
import { Action } from "./action";

export type Todo = {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
}

interface State {
  todos: Todo[];
}
const initialState: State = {
  todos: []
};

const reducer = produce((draft: Draft<State>, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_TODOS_FULFILLED": {
      const todos = action.payload.data;
      return todos;
    }
  }
}, initialState);

export default reducer;
```

### Action

```
// action.ts
import axios from "axios";
import type { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import type { Todo } from './reducer'

export const getTodos = (): {
  type: "GET_TODOS";
  payload: Promise<AxiosResponse<Todo[]>>;
} => ({
  type: "GET_TODOS",
  payload: axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
});

export type Action = ReturnType<typeof getTodos>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out by myself.
The problem was the incorrect typing of `useAppDispatch`.

So in `store.ts` instead of having

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

We should have

```
import type { ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
export type AppThunk<RT = void> = ThunkAction<
  Promise<RT>,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  AnyAction
>;
export type AppThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, void, Action>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppThunkDispatch>();
```

And then in `action.ts` we could write our `thunk` actions like this:

```
export const getTodos =
  (): AppThunk<{ type: "SET_TODOS"; payload: Todo[] }> => (dispatch) =>
    axios
      .get<Todo[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .then((todos) => dispatch(setTodos(todos)));

export const setTodos = (
  todos: Todo[]
): {
  type: "SET_TODOS";
  payload: Todo[];
} => ({
  type: "SET_TODOS",
  payload: todos
});
```

And lastly for using dispatch anywhere in our app:

```
dispatch(getTodos()).then((todos) => console.log(todos));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a promise and then you can use .then like this.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { getTodos } from "./action";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./store";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const myPromise = ()=>Promise.resolve(dispatch(getTodos())); /// creating promise 

  useEffect(() => {
    myPromise().then((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res.value.data)
    })
              
  }, []);
  return <div className="App">Hello World!</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Hope you are looking something like this.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a solution to correctly type my actions. Finding a workaround for "not typing" them would be my last shot.

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` would return whatever your action (thunk) returns.

It seems the part

```
({
  type: "GET_TODOS",
  payload: axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
})
```

might be wrong: what you wanted is probably

```
const getTodos = (): ThunkAction => (dispatch) => 
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then(todos => {
    dispatch({type: "GET_TODOS", payload: todos}); 
    return todos;
  });
```

This way you both have your action fired and your Promise returned from dispatch with todos payload.

You may also want to type your ThunkAction with generics according to https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-redux-thunks

Comment: This is actually how `redux-promise-middleware` library works. Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise-middleware